# Limit list of users in owner dropdown

Tags: wagtail

Currently, the list of owners when editing a page includes all Users. If this list is thousands of users, it prevents the page from loading.

Is there a way to edit the queryset so that it only includes staff users or users with a certain permission?

Comment: Wagtail's out-of-the-box configuration doesn't provide an 'owner' dropdown. Are you using Puput as a blog app on top of Wagtail, by any chance?

Comment: You can see the owner field here in WagTail: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/models.py line ~257 . The model is derived from the Page model.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by creating a model manager which by default filters to show only `is_staff=True` users. Then I changed everywhere else I was using my custom user model to use a `raw_objects` manager which does not filter.

```
class BaseMyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """ This one doesn't filter any results. 
    """
    pass

class MyUserManager(BaseMyUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyUserManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            is_staff=True)
```

Then in the models.py

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ... custom fields for the User model.

    objects = MyUserManager()
    raw_objects = BaseMyUserManager()
```